# jQuery $.post function failing

Tags: jquery

I have no idea why this `jQuery` function is not working. It's very simple and the result should be obvious. I've done several tests on the `html` and `php` files to verify they are working properly and they are. The problem is definitely in this function.

**function**

```
$('#sui').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();    

    $.post('sign_in.php', { email: email, password: password }, function(data) {         
          $('#errors').text(data);          
    });
});
```

Now I've tested this function by putting alerts in different places. If I put this code in

```
$('#sui').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    alert (email + password); // inserted this line

    $.post('sign_in.php', { email: email, password: password }, function(data) {         
          $('#errors').text(data);          
    });
});
```

then I get an alert box with the values from my email and password text inputs. However if I move the alert down inside the $.post function like this

```
$('#sui').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();    

    $.post('sign_in.php', { email: email, password: password }, function(data) {
         alert ('hi'); // never shows up
         alert (data); // never shows up        
         $('#errors').text(data);       
    });
});
```

As noted in the comments the alert never shows, the page refreshes after submitting the form and I'm left on the original page like nothing ever happened the 'errors' div never receives any message. My first thought was that maybe I had another field in my `html` file that had the id of "email" "password" or "sui" but I don't, these are all unique id's. Then I checked that the `php` file was actually returning data, and it is. If you would like to see the relevant html and php code i will show it. Anyways any help is appreciated, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're binding an event handler to a form submit button. The problem appears that the form is being submitted before `$.post` has a chance to handle the response.

What you want to do is prevent the form from submitting.

Try this:

```
$('#sui').submit(function (e) {      // added 'e' to catch the jQuery event
    e.preventDefault();             /* prevent the default action from happening, 
                                       in this case submitting the form */
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();    

    $.post('sign_in.php', { email: email, password: password }, function(data) {
         alert ('hi'); // never shows up
         alert (data); // never shows up        
         $('#errors').text(data);       
    });
});
```

As an aside, I would suggest the [jQuery jqXHR Promise](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) interface:

```
$.post('sign_in.php', { email: email, password: password })
    .done(function(data) {
        // success
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        // error
     });
```

Also, I personally prefer to use `console.log()` along with developer tools (F12 in Chrome and IE) for debugging instead of `alert()` because with most modern browsers you can inspect objects.

For example, if you wanted to look at what the jqXHR object looks like in the `.fail()` method, `alert(jqXHR)` would show `Object [Object]`, whereas `console.log(jqXHR)` would show the entire jqXHR object.

Comment: In addition, the third paramater in `$.post()` isn't the error handler, it's success handler. Attach the `.fail()` function (or `.error()`) to the end of `$.post()` with the anonymous function passed to that instead.

Comment: thanks, this worked, its now showing the responses. This was working last night, why is this happening now and is this the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: In other words should I be attaching a `.done()` and handling the success there?

Comment: btw, the edited code is not working like the original, the same problem occurs, well slightly. The .fail happens every time because the form is still being submitted before the request reaches `.done()`. Just an FYI

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the function (updated my answer)

Comment: Yea I did, and it works. Is this the only way to prevent this from happening? I was under the impression that `.done()` would only be performed when the action was complete. Is this wrong? Sorry for all the questions, this just feels like a hacky solution with the `e.preventDefault()` and I'm trying to get into good practices from the start

Comment: If it feels hacky, an alternative would be to avoid using a form tag, and instead of binding the click event to a submit button, bind it to a regular `button` (or href). An advantage to using a `form` element and overriding its default action is you can allow users with Javascript disabled to still use your site. `e.preventDefault()` is not really there as a hack, rather it's there to give you options, especially in the area of accessibility.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well when it's explained like that it feels less hacky. Thanks for all the info, have a nice day!